# Unable to write all binary data from serial port to text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I am currently trying to save binary data from a serial port. The problem for me now is that it is only saving one value to the text file. I would like to save all the values obtained from the serial port to the text file. Below I attached my code. Thanks.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
   port='COM4',
   baudrate=9600,
   timeout = 1,
   parity= serial.PARITY_NONE,
   stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
   bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)

while 1:
    if ser.inWaiting():
        val = ser.readline()    
        outf = open("message1.txt", 'wb')
        outf.write(val)
        outf.close()
        print(val)
```

Comment: Well, you're reopening and rewriting the file from the beginning every time a character is received - what did you expect to happen?  Open the file in append mode, or better yet, *leave* it open for the duration of the program.

Comment: @jasonharper Sorry to bother you but may I know how can I leave the file open for the duration of the program? Should i remove the outf.close() so it remains open or is there any other changes I can make to further improve it?